# How do I write to and read from a file in cordova (ionic) when I have the path of the file to be read?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a function which takes the path as the parameter? The path is of the form `file: //storage`.

Comment: check this out http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

Comment: Could you help me with the implementation? I need to read and write operate on a file with the following path : file: //storage/sdcard/1.txt

Comment: And the path is dynamically changing

Comment: @j doe check out this working non ionic sample in this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Answer (score 0):

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
```

First Inject ngCordova module then in you run do something like this

```
run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaFile) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   console.log(cordova.file);
   $cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, "1.txt")
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and if you want to use this in controller

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaFile) {
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
console.log(cordova.file);
$cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, "1.txt")
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
})
```

also make sure you have included ng-cordova.js in your index file and file plugin for all of this work . Let me know if got any problem. Thanks